# How to run a background job every few seconds using django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, background-process

I would like to know how to execute a function or file every few seconds using django so that I can populate my database with data obtained from this function call.

I need a function to be executed every 5 seconds, this function will scrape a website and save its information into my database, this information will be used by one of my template views to generate a `plotly` graph.

I've read about Celery and `async` stuff but couldn't figure out a way to put this into practice.

If someone answers this, please tell me where should I put this `job` file in my django project or if I should just add a function to an existing file.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/ui/django-rq

Comment: You can use Celery for that, but why bother - since that has nothing to do with Django's purpose or direct operation, why not just write a standalone script that will do your bidding and set it to run as a cron job?

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install django-crontab
```

add `django_crontab` in the `installed apps` in settings file

create a file called `cron.py` in the project directory and write the function in this file

in settings.py add the time

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('* * * * 5', 'cron.my_scheduled_job')
]
```

then from terminal

```
python manage.py crontab add
```

Comment: It says `ImportError: No module named 'django-crontab'` when I execute `python manage.py crontab add`. I added django-crontab like this in my settings.py: `INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django-crontab',`. It also has all the other djano.stuff and my apps names (core, accounts...)

Comment: did you installed it? see the 1st line of my answer, first install from terminal, if you are using virtualenv the activate the virtualenv the run the pip install django-crontab

Comment: yea, it was already installed, I checked it using `pip freeze`

Comment: ah, just fixed it, in the installed apps it should be django_crontab and not django-crontab

Comment: sorry bro, miss typed it, :) @gabrielbelini

Comment: It is working but I dont think the job is being called, should I create a function inside cron.py with the name `my_scheduled_job` ?

Comment: yup bro you need to create a function inside cron.py an write the code inside the function what you want to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146684/discussion-between-gabriel-belini-and-exprator).

Comment: @GabrielBelini bro always put underscore instead of (-) sign when you are adding to installed apps

Answer (score 0):

Something this simple could be achieved as a daemon rather than using a cron or celery etc. Take a look at [python-daemon](https://github.com/serverdensity/python-daemon) or confusingly,
 [another package with the same name](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/).

Answer (score 0):

add app on the top of list
step 1.
INSTALLED_APPS = [ # default django apps 'django_crontab',

#other apps
]

step 2.

save settings.py and run server

step 3.
if you are using in docker than docker-compose build before docker-compose-up